# Approach for associated model searching with Elasticsearch [Ruby, ActiveRecord, elasticsearch-model]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, activerecord, elasticsearch-model

I have a question about choosing the best approach in case of searching in `Elasticsearch`.

I have Ruby off Rails API, with `ActiveRecord`, together with `Elasticsearch` ( `elasticsearch-model` gem).

It's a simple API which returns `projects` (Project AR model), where I set up indexes:

```
mapping dynamic: false do
indexes :created_at, type: 'date'
end
```

Then I simply make a search on Elasticsearch and return AR relations directly from the controller. It's working perfectly.

Now I am trying to add `categories` to `projects`, as `categories has_many projects`, and `projects belongs_to categories`. I am wondering about two things:

How now should I make a query to get projects from specific categories, should I reimplement it to return `result = Category.search(...)` and return `result.jobs`, or still seeking by `projects`, but searching by `category_id`?

How to combine `Category` and `Project` in Elasticsearch to make possible to search for projects from a specific category, and from various multiple categories? Merge mappings?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first though here is that you're use case is very simple. You don't need Elasticsearch at all. You can simplify and use just ActiveRecord, select by SQL and return records. You don't need any of the features provided by Elasticsearch for your use case, you're just creating more work for yourself by doing so.

However, I'll assume your developing iteratively and your usage will get significantly more complex. Justifying the use of Elasticsearch.

**Relational and Non-Relational Data**

ActiveRecord is a [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) for relational data. Typicalhttps://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/documents-indices.htmlly it sits on top of a [Structured Query Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) powered relational database. It supports relations (associations in Rails parlance) really well.

Elasticsearch is a [non relational document store](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/documents-indices.html), storing information as JSON in an inverted index. This allows for very quick full-text search (amongst other uses). It doesn't support relations between documents very well. It is designed to not relate data! It wants you to not store relations and to instead repeat data constantly, the opposite of the SQL approach. This is called denormalization, more on this below.

These are very different ways of think about data storage! That doesn't mean they don't play well together. They can work well together if used correctly. However, they take different ways of thinking. It's important to have a good grasp of the fundamentals behind each in order to make sound judgements on how to use them, in my opinion.

Elasticsearch has **great** [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html). I recommend you spend a couple hours reading up on it.

**How does  Elasticsearch do associations?**

You care about a basic `has-many` association in your question, so how does Elastic handle these? What are the options?

[There are 4 major options.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/relations.html) I think you should [denormalize](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/denormalization.html) your data here.

I think you want to return all projects from certain categories. So you should create a index which contains a document per category. Each category should have within it a complete list of it's projects. You can then query for a category and return all it's projects.

This is one approach. Your use case is so simple that it feels like overkill to me, you could solve this using any of the 4 major options for Elasticsearch linked above. Or ideally by not using Elasticsearch at all.

If you provide more detail on your use case, I'd be able to discuss more what approach you could use.

Comment: The reason of using Elasticsearch, was to simply try for the first time inside the team. However, it was no decision of mine. One of the requirements is a full-text search, however from my perspective, it can be achieved by using Postgres, and simply ActiveRecord, but the team decided to always use MySQL and give a try to the Elasticsearch. I will try your recommendations tomorrow. Many appreciation from my site. I totally agree that the approach with ES is harder than AR.

Answer (score 1):

// mapping (nested categories)

```
 mapping dynamic: false do
  indexes :created_at, type: 'date'
  indexes :categories, type: 'nested' do
    indexes :name, type: :text, analyzer: :english
  end 
 end
```

// json

```
  def as_indexed_json(_options = nil)
  { 
   created_at: created_at,
   # in case project belong_to category  
   # categories: [category.name, Category::DEFAULT].map do ... 
   categories: categories.map do |category|
     {
       name: category.name
     }
   end
  } 
 end
```

// search function(**elasticsearch DSL**) as you want to search projects by categories

```
def by_categories(categories)
  filters = []
  categories.each { |category|
    filters.push term: {"categories.name":category.name}
  }
  Project.__elasticsearch__.search(
     query: {            
        nested: {
           path: "categories",
           query: {
              bool: {
                 filter:{
                    bool:{
                        should:filters                                       
                    }
                  }
               }
            }
        }    
     }
  )
end
```

Comment: In my case, the project belongs_to category, so the model only has a category_id attribute. So I can only do like project.category, instead of all categories. It could work, in case of project has_many categories, but how to approach it the opposite way?

Comment: well, a project should belong_to category , it's ok. You can add more one fake category "all" each index ["all", "particular category name"] to support search all categories)

Comment: And how to fetch albo subcategories from a specific category?

Comment: i guess that sub_category belong_to zero or one group_category, right?  so that beside "all" , each project belongs to "sub category" should be added one more "group category".["all", "sub cat", "spec cat"]

Comment: It's self-referenced model:  `Category id: "25cd43a2-bc03-4fa7-977e-df1b6c6a5c65", name: "Nature", description: nil, parent_id: nil, created_at: "2020-02-27 18:06:57", updated_at: "2020-02-27 18:06:57`. If parent_id nil, it means it's a category, and if there is subcategory it is `Category id: "6e41c695-8a43-4be5-974b-95fb29e2bb25", name: "Forest", description: nil, parent_id: "25cd43a2-bc03-4fa7-977e-df1b6c6a5c65", created_at: "2020-02-27 18:07:33", updated_at: "2020-02-27 18:07:33">`. Don't know how to handle it in elasticsearch-model gem.